# Java jar -C option

Tags: java, jar

I've start to read about jars, But I cannot understard how `jar -C` works.

I've tried the following command

```
jar cfv Some.jar -C innertest\ForDelete.class .
```

when I am in `E:\eclipse_workspace\Test\bin\test>`.

So I expect to have `PartJar.jar` and files the files in it which are not in `test` directory. But after executing the command the result is `added manifest` and only manifest file is created.

So if I try `jar cfv Some.jar -C innertest .` it will work, but what if I want to add only 3 files in this directory not the whole directory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not easy to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: The -C option names a *directory.* Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there is a solution which does not involve multiple use of -C:

```
jar cfv my.jar -C myDir file1 -C myDir file2
```

A possible workaround, if applicable to your case, could be to put only the files you need inside a new directory and use:

```
jar cfv my.jar -C newDir .
```